# Unable to connect to Database: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: SASL Authentication failed on database 'conci': Authentication failed

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I work in Codeigniter
There is my database http://prntscr.com/ffq36m
I try to connect to it from Codeigniter
private function connect(){
        $options = array();

```
    try{        
        if (file_exists('installation.php')){

            require './installation.php';exit;
        }else{

            var_dump($this->connection_string, $options);die;
            $this->connection = new MongoClient($this->connection_string, $options);

            $this->db = $this->connection->{$this->dbname};

            return $this;
        }
    }catch (MongoConnectionException $e){
        if (file_exists('installation.php')){
            require './installation.php';exit;
        }else{
            show_error("Unable to connect to Database: {$e->getMessage()}", 500);
        }
    }
}
```

There is an answer
string(51) "mongodb://imediasun:sunimedia@localhost:27017/conci" array(0) { }
And Finaly I have an error

Unable to connect to Database: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: SASL Authentication failed on database 'conci': Authentication failed.

There is my mongo server
http://prntscr.com/ffq470

please Help me with this error

Comment: User imediasun created on mongodb??

Comment: User imediasun created in conci db

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffq6kj

Comment: Are you able to login with the same credentials using mongo client to conci database??

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Well, can you add "authSource=dbWithUserCredentials')" to the end of the mongo URL and try???

Comment: Your end URL would be "mongodb://imediasun:sunimedia@localhost:27017/conci?authSource=dbWithUserCredentials"

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffq90a

Comment: Is this right ? string(84) "mongodb://imediasun:sunimedia@localhost:27017/conci?authSource=dbWithUserCredentials"  I have the same error

Comment: I don't think you followed incorrect syntax to log into mongodb from cmd line, you haven't given space between -u and -p. Correct one would be `mongo -u imediasun -p 'sunimedia' --authenticationDatabase admin`. If you are unable to login, then you are entering incorrect credentials

Comment: `authenticationDatabase admin` might change based on the database the user was created.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffqces

Comment: your credentials seem to be incorrect. Try with the correct ones. Or create a new user and try

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffqd2n  As you see I have such user

Comment: user could be there, but what about password ? Is it correct? You should have got connected to it using mongo shell if it was correct

Comment: I tell you it is correct http://prntscr.com/ffqema

Comment: Can you try with `mongo -u imediasun -p 'sunimedia' --authenticationDatabase admin` instead of `conci` from mongo shell?

Comment: password isn't visible to me. So, can't validate.. :)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffqfgp Sorry I see in usual shell such picture, How can I put user information I dont know why but there is a user in robomongo and the pass but is epsent interminal shell

Comment: Sorry, am not aware of any more options.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffqiof Now I can login

Comment: Glad to see that you fixed it!!